# Jooq update return value

Tags: java, sql, jooq, vertica

I try to update rows in table and get results after.
If I do

```java
dsl.update(TABLE)
   .set(TABLE.ROW, newRow)
   .where(TABLE.ROW_2.eq(
            dsl.select(ANOTHER_TABLE.ID)
               .from(ANOTHER_TABLE)
               .where(ANOTHER_TABLE.GUID.eq(guid))
   )).execute()
```

it returns 1. But if I do

```java
dsl.update(TABLE)
   .set(TABLE.ROW, newRow)
   .where(TABLE.ROW_2.eq(
            dsl.select(ANOTHER_TABLE.ID)
               .from(ANOTHER_TABLE)
               .where(ANOTHER_TABLE.GUID.eq(guid))
   )).returningResult(TABLE.ROW_3).fetchOne()
```

it returns empty result. But I want to get TABLE.ROW_3 after update. Whats the problem?

Comment: What database product are you using?

Comment: I use vertica 9 db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertica doesn't support `UPDATE .. RETURNING` like PostgreSQL, as can be seen in the Vertica docs:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/UPDATE.htm

The jOOQ documentation of [`UpdateReturningStep::returningResult`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdateReturningStep.html#returningResult(org.jooq.SelectField)) reflects this by not listing `SQLDialect.VERTICA` in its `@Support` annotation:

```java
@Support({AURORA_POSTGRES,COCKROACHDB,DB2,FIREBIRD,ORACLE,POSTGRES,SQLSERVER})
```

There's currently no workaround for this. If you want to avoid using such API, you could use the [`jOOQ-checker`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/tools/checker-framework/) module in your build to produce compilation errors whenever you use API that is not supported by `VERTICA`